# Get image_id of all images in google drive folder

Tags: google-drive-api

Good afternoon. I am currently working on a project and I need to use python to get all the image_ids of the images in a folder. I have tried to use

```
query = f"parents = '{folder_id}'"
files = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
```

but for some reason this returns an id which is different to the real image id you can find in drive. Any tips?

Comment: Please show an example of the response you are getting and the response that you would have expected to see.

Comment: What I am getting: 'id': '1tfPYMuhRSNC5pFtKcccnau11-RAoZ4nH'                                             What I should be getting: '18h-MkLdhqeHZ45pIiDZ3G5RkqJm6Pwh0'

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Your query parameter is malformed.*

#### More Information:

The `q` parameter needs to be rewritten as:

```
'folderId' in parents and mimeType='image/jpeg'
```

where `folderId` is the ID of the folder in which you wish to search.

The `q` parameter allows you to specify properties of the files you are trying to list - so you're saying here *"List all files that have a mimetype of `image/jpeg`, where `folderId` is contained in its list of parents."*

Answer (score -1):

Im suprised that works at all since parents use **in** not **=**

Example

To return all the files in the folder.

```
parents in '{folder_id}'
```

This would give you all the jpeg files on your drive

```
mimeType='image/jpeg'
```

You can put them both together using and

```
parents in 'root' and mimeType='image/jpeg'
```

Comment: I have just changed it to query = f"parents in '{folder_id}'" but that did not change the results. The id that service.files(0.list(q=query).execute is different to the one of the url of the image.

Comment: All files.list does is return a list of files that it has.  By adding the Q parameter you are telling it you would like to only see the files within the folder called folder_id.     Im not sure i understand what the issue or what it has to do with a url of the image.

Comment: what I want is to get the image_ids of each of the images in the folder, but I am not sure how to do it. Is there any other option apart from files.list?